# Determining relativistic velocities of two moving bodies at an angle

Tags: special-relativity

I'm currently doing a practice problem from a special relativity textbook and wanted to see if my methodology works. The Question reads:

"Two rocketships leave the earth at equal speeds of c/2 and make equal angles of 60 degrees with the x-direction. find the relative velocity of the two rocketships".

The question doesn't specify what frame to find the velocity from so I'll just assume you find it for the earth's perspective and one of the rocket's perspective.

Using some simple trig, I found the rockets to be moving apart at 0.866c in the earth's frame. To find the velocity from one of the rocket's perspectives I used the equation $U_y'=\frac{U_y\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}{ 1-\frac{vU_x}{c^2}}$ but I'm pretty sure I did something wrong because I attempted the calculation a couple times and I got a value greater than c on one attempt.

Very interested to see what you all get or to see if I'm even using the right equation. All feedback is welcome and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The velocity addition formula in this case is:

$V_{x} = \frac {V_{x}^{'} + v}{1+\frac{vV_{x}^{'}}{c^{2}}}$ 
along $x$-axis.

Comment: From my understanding that equation is used whenever the velocity is parallel to the velocity between the frames. In this case, the relative velocity between the rockets would be perpendicular to the velocity between frames. If I have that wrong then I may need to reread some material.